# Dovecot not working pop3 with postfix

Tags: linux, pop3, dovecot

telnet localhost pop3
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

netstat -l

tcp        0      0 *:www                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdoma:ipp *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:smtp                  *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:mysql *:*                     LISTEN

when i run this service dovecot start i got

start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.553" (uid=1000 pid=26250 comm="start) interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init"))

on Dovecot.conf

```
protocols = imap imaps pop3 pop3s
disable_plaintext_auth = no
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
mail_location = maildir:/var/spool/mail/%d/%n
mail_access_groups = mail
first_valid_uid = 106
first_valid_gid = 106
protocol imap {

}

protocol pop3 {
listen=*:110
pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
}
protocol lda {
  postmaster_address = samer@aiu.com
  mail_plugins = quota
  log_path = /var/log/dovecot-deliver.log
  info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-deliver.log
}

auth default {
mechanisms = digest-md5 plain
passdb sql {
args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
}
userdb sql {
args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
}
user = root
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get this message on the command line:

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.553" (uid=1000 pid=26250 comm="start) interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init"))
```

It indicates that you're not doing service dovecot restart as root. So make sure you do:

```
sudo service dovecot restart
```

Answer (score 0):

The directive `protocols = imap imaps pop3 pop3s` should be sufficient to activate pop3 with dovecot. You can add

```
listen = *
```

to be sure dovecot will listen on all available interfaces. You can verify this by `netstat -apn | grep 110`. Are there any failures while starting dovecot? Can you post the dovecot related logs?

By default, dovecot logs to syslog, you can explicitly specify the log files:

```
# Log file to use for error messages, instead of sending them to syslog.
# /dev/stderr can be used to log into stderr.
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log

# Log file to use for informational and debug messages.
# Default is the same as log_path.
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot.info.log
```

Comment: i did this : netstat -apn | grep 110
but nothing it's like the dovecot not runing

Comment: and nothing about dovecot in mail.log or mail.err

Comment: Are you sure this are dovecot logs and not the ones for postfix? (I've extended my answer about  logging)

Comment: does it all the same .... the postfix and dovecot in /var/log/mail.log and i didnt find any thing in logsys
and about dovecot.log doesnt exist